# How to extract ddl for oracle db links?

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2, dblink

Is there anyway to extract ddl for all database links?
I would like to get in sql and recreate them via sql.

I can use below and it works for PUBLIC user but for non public user it doesn't give me db link owner.

```
Set long 1000
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('DB_LINK',db.db_link,db.owner) from dba_db_links db;

Sample link owner and name
Owner   db_link
public  link1
public  link2
user1   link3
```

If I ran above select it will give me below, #3 doesn't have username in it.

```
Output from above SELECT
1. create public database link "link1" using "db_alias"
2. create public database link "link2" using "db_alias"
3. create database link "link3" using "db_alias"
```

I recreate links using SYS and don't want to create #3 as SYS user.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that even as SYS user you can't easity create dblink for another user (except of public dblink).
Even if you run `create database link your_user.link3 using "db_alias"` it's owner will be `SYS`.
Possible hacks are connect as another user
 (you may add `conn` into SQL*Plus script if you have credentials)
Or create procedure for user that need to have dblink that run `create database link` command with parameters and call it from sys.

Answer (score 0):

this should help with links that do a "connect to"

```
SELECT MYCOMMAND 
FROM 
(
select trim(l.owner)||'__'||trim(l.db_link)||'__'||trim(l.username)   ||'__'||trim(l.host) , '10'
, ' connect '||trim(l.owner)||'/CCCCCCCC@'||TRIM(INSTANCE_NAME)
 AS MYCOMMAND                 
from dba_db_links l , V$INSTANCE i , dba_users u  
where l.username = u.username
and l.username is not null 
and l.username <> ' '
UNION ALL
select trim(l.owner)||'__'||trim(l.db_link)||'__'||trim(l.username)||'__'||trim(l.host) , '20'
, ' DROP DATABASE LINK  '||trim(l.db_link)||' ; ' AS MYCOMMAND
from dba_db_links l , V$INSTANCE i , dba_users u  
where l.username = u.username
and l.username is not null 
and l.username <> ' '
UNION ALL
select trim(l.owner)||'__'||trim(l.db_link)||'__'||trim(l.username)||'__'||trim(l.host) , '30'
, ' CREATE DATABASE LINK  '||trim(l.db_link)
||' CONNECT TO "'||trim(l.username)||'"'
||' IDENTIFIED BY "NNNNNNNN" '
||' USING '||trim(l.host) ||' ; 'AS MYCOMMAND
from dba_db_links l , V$INSTANCE i , dba_users u  
where l.username = u.username
and l.username is not null 
and l.username <> ' '
ORDER BY 1,2,3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get ddl from db links, run the output of the command below:

set pages 999;
set long 90000;

```
SELECT 'SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl(''DB_LINK'',''' || db_link || ''',''' || owner || ''') FROM dual;' 
FROM dba_db_links 
WHERE db_link 
IN ('DB_LINK1',
    'DB_LINK2',
    'DB_LINK3');
```

For create a db link for other user, with user SYS execute the DDL below:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK "OWNER.DBLINK_NAME"
   CONNECT TO "USER" IDENTIFIED BY "Password_user"
   USING 'ALIAS';
```

Answer (score 0):

Very useful, I have just changed `l.username` in `l.owner` because otherwise I can't see all db links for users different from the connected one.
In addition instead of `instance name` I have set `db_unique_name`:

```
SELECT MYCOMMAND 
FROM 
(
select trim(l.owner)||'__'||trim(l.db_link)||'__'||trim(l.username)   ||'__'||trim(l.host) , '10'
, ' connect '||trim(l.owner)||'/********@'||TRIM(DB_UNIQUE_NAME)
AS MYCOMMAND                 
from dba_db_links l , V$DATABASE i , dba_users u  
where l.owner = u.username
and l.username is not null 
and l.username <> ' '
UNION ALL
select trim(l.owner)||'__'||trim(l.db_link)||'__'||trim(l.username)||'__'||trim(l.host) , '20'
, ' DROP DATABASE LINK  '||trim(l.db_link)||' ; ' AS MYCOMMAND
from dba_db_links l , V$DATABASE i , dba_users u  
where l.owner = u.username
and l.username is not null 
and l.username <> ' '
UNION ALL
select trim(l.owner)||'__'||trim(l.db_link)||'__'||trim(l.username)||'__'||trim(l.host) , '30'
, ' CREATE DATABASE LINK  '||trim(l.db_link)
||' CONNECT TO "'||trim(l.username)||'"'
||' IDENTIFIED BY "**********" '
||' USING '||trim(l.host) ||' ; 'AS MYCOMMAND
from dba_db_links l , V$DATABASE i , dba_users u  
where l.owner = u.username
and l.username is not null 
and l.username <> ' '
ORDER BY 1,2,3
);
```

cheers

Mario